# While loop and cin

Tags: c++, while-loop

The code below should ask the user his weight and if the user puts > 15 it should do a while loop to increase it to 50
The code compiles successfully but no matter if you put > 15 it wont do the while loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{


int weight;

cout << "Current weight?" << endl;
cin >> weight;
cout << "Your weight:" << weight << endl;
if (weight > 15) {
        while (weight == 50) {
            weight = weight + 1;
            cout << "Weight:" << weight << endl;
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is doing the while loop.. its only printing at 50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while(weight==50){
    weight = weight +1;
    cout <<"Weight:"<<weight<<endl;
}
```

The above loop will keep on going as long as `weight` is equal to `50` which, by judging from what you have written in the question, is not what you are looking for.

To fix the problem, change the *loop-condition* into something more suitable; didn't you want to keep on looping as long as `weight` is *less-than* `50`?

Comment: But     == means equal to,so shouldn't it actually run until its 50?
Thanks for the help as you helped me fix it,but I just dont understand why == didnt work.

Comment: @ScottKim No, the condition governs if the loop should keep on going or not, it does **not** mean *"when it is time to stop"*. `while (weight == 50) work;` says that we should keep doing *`work`* as long as `weight` is `50`.

Answer (score 0):

A while loop statement in C/C++ programming language repeatedly executes a target statement as long as a given condition is true.

Comment: While loop is executed until condition becomes false.

Answer (score 0):

weight ==50 condition will fail if you enter weight value other than fifty. 
To do what you have mentioned modify condition in while loop.

```
weight == 50
```

to

```
weight < 50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ran this program step-by-step, using a debugger, and you added watches of the values of variables, you would see what's going on.

Your development environment (what you use to write code) likely has an integrated debugger; alternatively, use another dev. env.'s debugger, or a stand-alone debugger like gdb for the command line, kdbg for KDE, ddd for any X environment etc. (those are all on Linux; other platforms may have other debuggers).